# VB .Net get path with OpenFileDialog

Tags: .net, file

i loaded Excel Worksheet like this

```
WorkB = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\ExcelForm.xls")
```

but now i wanna load file by choosing path with dialog box(OpenFileDialog).
how can i make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
If ofd.showdialog = dialogresult.ok then
     WorkB = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ofd.filename)
End If
```